# Windows partition not appearing when installing Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, partition, windows

I have a ~500gb hard drive that I intend to split 50/50 for Windows 10 and Linux Mint 17. The Windows partition is 232GB and the Linux partition is, at the moment, uncreated. When I run Mint off my pen drive and go to install it, it shows the hard drive as 500gb of 'free space'. I can't install because it will wipe my Windows install.

How can I get the partition to show in Mint?

Comment: I have a hunch that Windows 10 uses a Filesystem Type that the Mint installer doesn't recognize, therefore the drive is empty in regards to the installer.  I would file a few bugs.  1 for the installer and another for parted.

Comment: Even if the filesystem is not recognized, it should still come up as something along the lines of `unknown`, should it not? If it shows the *whole* disk as completely unallocated, then perhaps it is using an unrecognized partitioning scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Always make a back up first!

I did this the other day installing Ubuntu 14.10 on a Windows 10 drive. When the installation got to the part where you choose how to install I chose "something else". At that point no operating systems were detected, however, the partition showed up as "Windows bootloader".

You can mark the partition as "do not use" and then resize the "do not use" partition to make free space for linux.

The linux partition needs to be partitioned to ext4 (default), ext3, xfs, or btrfs. You also need a couple of GB to partition for linux-swap space.

Comment: It shows the entire hard drive as un-allocated space.

Comment: Have you tried checking things out with gparted before starting the installation? Either that or maybe you should try the partitioning in Windows before you start.

Comment: How would I set it up on Windows? Is there a program I should use?

Comment: @Nanor http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-format-hard-disk-partition#create-format-hard-disk-partition=windows-7 and this vid is a bit newer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXn2CQkURgo

Comment: @Nanor you might want to try using gparted from an Ubuntu 14.10 live iso. Windows 10 showed up on my disk during install so it's worth a shot, it linux, it gparted and it's familiar. If it's just a Mint bug, you could use the Ubuntu disk to format a couple of partitions to use for the Mint install. Choose something else from the installer menu in Mint and then install directly to your preformatted partition.

Comment: @Nanor http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.10/

Comment: @Nanor I almost forgot. Make sure you have shut down properly from windows, you won't be able to edit the partitions properly if the disk has been suspended or is in hibernate!!

Comment: I tried using gparted with an Ubuntu live iso. Ubuntu picked up the Windows install and also another partition I formatted as exFat with Windows disk manager. I converted the exFat partition to ext4 and booted up the Mint installer. It still shows the entire hard drive as 500.1gb of free space. Should I try using gparted again and format it something other than ext4 or is the whole Mint dream a bit hopeless at this stage? Alternatively, would I be able to wipe the whole HD and install Mint then try install Windows 10 on another partition?

Comment: @Nanor If you are okay with re-installing windows you might want to try marking the entire partition as unused and then resizing it during installation. I had problems with W8 one time but has worked otherwise just MAKE A BACKUP and expect to fail. Alternatively it should be no problem to install mint and then Windows 10 except you would have to reinstall Grub after installing windows to regain control of the MBR. You can do that manually from a live disk if you know how or you can use boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair and http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Comment: @Nanor if you install Mint first, just remember that Windows MUST be installed on a "primary" partition and not a logical or extended one.

Comment: @Nanor and as suggested, I would file a bug with Linux Mint to get that issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... as I have tried this my self on a machine that did support both "legacy boot" and the new standard i simply disabled the legacy in the BIOS, and then the win10 partition showed up. It could seems like *nix could have periodic "failures" seeing partitions on the new boot format :/